# Cannot find "module dq-sql-parser without .js extension", did you mean to import "module dq-sql-parser with .js extension"

Tags: node.js, typescript, package.json, tsc, typescript-module-resolution

I frequently encounter an error when attempting to install a module using npm install. Could someone please take a look at this example?

I'm trying to install the dt-sql-parser package with the command:

```
npm install dt-sql-parser
```

As per the dt-sql-parser GitHub readme, I'm following these steps in my code:

```
import GenericSQL from 'dt-sql-parser/dist/parser/generic';

const parser = new GenericSQL();

const correctSql = 'select id,name from user1;';
const errors = parser.validate(correctSql);
console.log(errors);
```

However, when I run the script using:

```
node dt-sql-parser-readme-script.js
```

I encounter the following error message:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '...dt-sql-parser/dist/parser/generic' ... Did you mean to import dt-sql-parser/dist/parser/generic.js?
```

How can I address this issue in my daily workflow? Do I need to modify all the problematic modules?

Here's the content of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "antlr4-test",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dt-sql-parser": "^4.0.0-beta.4.1"
  }
}
```

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I'm attempting to utilize the npm packages without having to modify them

Comment: From the `tsc` tag, it looks like you may be using TypeScript. If so, modern versions of typescript require you to import files with a .js extension. See the error message? It suggests you add `.js` to the import statement.